# CDI - conditional installation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, jboss-weld

I have several components which are application scoped.  Depending on which environment I am in, I want to install one or the other.  In JBoss Seam, I would use @Install(false), then configure the bean that I wanted through components.xml.

Is there a similar method for doing this in CDI / WELD?

Thanks,

Walter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can always use a producer method and decide which implementation to instantiate based on some configuration of yours. Remember that in CDI the amount of xml is put to minimum.

So, something like:

```
@Produces
public Component createComponent() {
   if (configuration.isSomething()) {
       return new ComponentImpl1();
   } else {
       return new ComponentImpl2();
   }
}
```

Comment: Right, ok, I think I remember Pete showing this example.  I think this will work for me.

Comment: I have another use case, I am thinking that I will write an extension.  When the server starts up, I will determine if I want to install or register that bean at that point in time.  If I don't, I'll simply remove that definition from the container.  So, I am thinking that I would add an annotation indicating when to install it, if it shouldn't be installed, it is removed ...